# MySQL: Getting Posts from Categories

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data, database-relations

I'm trying to learn MySQL so I have created a little blog system.

**I have 3 tables in MySQL:**

`posts` :

```
id    |  title      
----------------
1     |  Post Title 1         
2     |  Post Title 2
```

`categories` :

```
id    |  title          | parent
--------------------------------
10     |  category10    | 0 
11     |  category11    | 0
12     |  category12    | 10
```

`post_category_relations` :

```
id    |  post_id   |   category_id
----------------------------------
1     |  1         |   10
2     |  2         |   12
3     |  3         |   11
```

Each post can have multiple categories, their relation is stored in post_category_relations:

So when I visit index.php?category=10 , I would like to get each post what is related to `category10` including the posts from its child folder `category12` as well.

**My Unfinished Snippet in PHP**

```
$folder_id = $_GET["category"]; // Get Category ID from the URL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts 
          JOIN categories
          JOIN post_category_relations
        // And I don't really know what should I do here
        // because I need the child categories first, then the relations
        // then I can get the post too from the post_id of the relations
       ";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I know that this will require advanced MySQL skills, but any help is appreciated! I already made this in PHP but I need to use 4 loops which is not the best way to do it when it's possible in MySQL, I just don't know yet how :)

Comment: first of all if you should escape your get input before you do a query (to prevent SQL injections)
this: 

    $folder_id = $_GET["category"]; 

should be:

    $folder_id = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET["category"]));

Comment: I also suggest you to read the articles @Denis provided. You'll learn a lot :) I myself read those several times.

Comment: Use MySQL session variables: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/. Also see this question for other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably find these articles by Phillip Keller interesting:

- [Tags: Database schemas](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html)
- [Tagsystems: performance tests](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html)

They cover tags, but your queries (i.e. `category1 and category2` vs `category1 or category2`, and the one you're trying to write) will be nearly identical.

See also this discussion on indexing hierarchical data: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

As well as the multitudes of threads on SO that related to nested sets, tags, categories, etc.

Comment: tags can't be used in this case, only tree (with paths, I assume). So +1 for hierarchical link, but you could write answer more detailed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. The multi-category queries will be very quite similar, though, whether they're tags or categories: his post2cat table will break down to the post2tag table discussed in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test my query , but I believe something like

```
select * from posts,post_category_relations where post.id=post_category_relations.post_id and
post_category_relations.category_id in (select id from categories where id=? or parent=?)
```

is what you are looking for .

Comment: @Rifat and where in the question is it mentioned that the categories are not in a single-depth tree ? Quoting , 'So when I visit index.php?category=10 , I would like to get each post what is related to category10 including the posts from its child folder category12 as well.'

Comment: the structure of the table itself is for multilevel isn't it?

Comment: @Rifat the structure of the table support multilevel category hierarchy .... as well as single level , as well as a 2-level hierarchy . Based on the info the OP provided , it can be assumed he meant the single-level ( the simplest case ) . If not , he should have clarified.

Answer (score 0):

This is one SQL:

```
 # Take post from castegory $cat_id
    (SELECT P.* 
        FROM 
          posts P, post_category_relations PR 
    WHERE 
       PR.category_id = {$cat_id} AND PR.post_id = P.id
     )
    UNION
    # Take all post from $cat_id child categories
    (SELECT P.* 
        FROM 
          posts P, post_category_relations PR, categories C
    WHERE 
       PR.category_id = C.parent AND PR.post_id = P.id 
       AND C.id = {$cat_id}
     )
```